# Ubuntu 22.04 WiFi hotspot won't allow connections

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 22.04

I can connect to the hotspot just fine, but the connected devices get disconnected almost immediately. Hotspot is set up using the settings tool in Ubuntu 22.04

I tried all the WiFi security options one by one, and there is the same behavior with each of them.

from journalctrl output

```
Nov 11 08:36:29 tortuga wpa_supplicant[19131]: wlo2: AP-STA-CONNECTED a6:81:e8:e3:73:66
Nov 11 08:36:29 tortuga wpa_supplicant[19131]: wlo2: EAPOL-4WAY-HS-COMPLETED a6:81:e8:e3:73:66
Nov 11 08:36:47 tortuga wpa_supplicant[19131]: wlo2: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED a6:81:e8:e3:73:66
```

How do I get this to work?  The Ubuntu 22.04 machine gets internet from a wired connection to the home router, the router provided DHCP and DNS services

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: No, the wifi works, I can pull the cable and connect to my android when it is acting as a hotspot fine and get internet, what I can't do is use the wifi as a hotspot for for other devices. I am not alone, it seems to be a common problem for 22.04 and none of the solutions make any difference